# Delete rows from SQL Server database by using BETWEEN condition just delete one record (the last one in range)

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have a table `Date` with these records (see screenshot):

[Image](https://imgur.com/a/abO1ncs)

This table has a column `DLT` of type `bit` (bool) that defaults to 0 (false).

I create an `Instead of delete` trigger for this table and when I delete a row, it isn't deleted for real, instead the the value of the `DLT` column is changed to 1 (true).

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrgDltDate] 
ON [dbo].[Date] 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DeletedID INT

    SELECT @DeletedID = deleted.DateID 
    FROM deleted

    UPDATE dbo.Date 
    SET DLT = 1, LastModificationDate = GETDATE() 
    WHERE DateID = @DeletedID
END
```

When I use "BETWEEN" condition for delete (Change "DLT" column value to 1) some records it just delete (Change "DLT" column value to 1) the last record in range for example :

```
DELETE FROM dbo.Date 
WHERE DateID BETWEEN 2 AND 6
```

it just delete (Change "DLT" column value to 1) for that record with DateID=6
but when I disable that trigger (`Instead of delete`), the "Between" works correctly. What's wrong ? tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger is only changing one row.  In SQL Server, triggers are set operations, so you should be thinking as sets:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TrgDltDate] ON [dbo].[Date] INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Date
        SET DLT = 1,
        LastModificationDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE DateID IN (SELECT d.DateID FROM Deleted d)
END;
```

That is, all the rows being deleted are passed into the trigger into the `deleted` "table" (actually a pseudo-table).  You want to delete all of them, not just one, so you can't store the id in a variable.

Comment: yesss . it works correctly. tnx a lot bro. one more question, what's the "d" in `(SELECT d.DateID FROM Deleted d)` ?

Comment: @mohamdJ.A. . . . That is a table alias.  It is not strictly needed in this case, but it is a good practice.

Comment: i got it . tnx again <3